# Word: remove space before paragraph with picture

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm writing a paper and adding charts surrounded by the text has been quite a pain. Currently I have one chart that sits in the top left corner of a page. There is approximately 4 cm left after the end of the last paragraph on the previous page, then comes the footnotes separator and the new paragraph starts on the next page.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Is there a way to force the text to use the empty space on the previous page?

Comment: I can't recreate your problem.  2 thoughts: have you checked your paragraph formatting settings-do you have a large value for spacing after a paragraph? Also, if you show all formatting marks, do you have any extra, blank paragraphs (or other non-printing items) in that space?  If you could post these pages, it would help to troubleshoot.

Comment: No, dav, there are no extra paragraph marks anywhere, that was the first thing I checked with shot hidden/special characters.
Also, the spacing after the paragraph is only 6 pt, so I doubt that would account for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the picture's wrap to "square" or "tight" instead of inline. If it's inline, it will look at the size (height) of the image, and see if it will fit in the remaining space on the page, which in this case, it won't.

Comment: Thanks, Anit Gandhi, but I've played with all the wrapping options and none of them affect the use of that empty space in any way. :(

Comment: That's unfortunate. I guess you could try changing the margins, but that would end up affecting the entire document. Potentially the footer might be affecting it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so I tried cropping the unwanted part of the photos in a Photo Editor before inserting into the word file... Lo Behold! the empty space before and after the image/photo disappeared... You could try it as well